# Export 2 CVS files to 1 Excel worksheet and another CSV file to the same workbook but different sheet

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I'm trying to accomplish this task below. I have searched and found some code that someone else has shared which seems to work with just basically saving each CVS file to its on worksheet. So here is what im trying to do:

Have 3 CSV files that I have created from SQL results using PowerShell. I want to take the first 3 CSV files and copy them to 1 worksheet on an .xslx and then I want to take the 3rd CSV file and copy it to the same workbook, but worksheet 2. I also want to format the data with set colors on the header and footer, but conditionally on the data on each row in between.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
param (
  [string]$InputPath = "C:\Users\bry30794\Documents\PS_Test",
  [string]$OutputPath = "C:\Users\bry30794\Documents\PS_Test",
  [string]$OutputFile = "test.xlsx"
)

$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application 
$Excel.Visible = $False 
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

# add 2 additional worksheets
$Workbook.Worksheets.Add() | Out-Null
$Workbook.Worksheets.Add() | Out-Null

##################################################
# Performance_Overall
##################################################
#Use the first worksheet in the workbook 
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
#Set name
$Worksheet.Name = "Performance_Overall" 

$csvFileNameWithPath = "$($InputPath)\test1.csv"
$Tempcsv = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFileNameWithPath)
$Tempsheet = $Tempcsv.Worksheets.Item(1)

#Copy contents of the CSV file
$Tempsheet.UsedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
#Paste contents of CSV into existing workbook
$Worksheet.Paste()
#Close temp workbook
$Tempcsv.Close()
#Select all used cells
$Range = $Worksheet.UsedRange
#Autofit the columns
$Range.EntireColumn.Autofit() | Out-Null

##[void]$ws.Range("A8").PasteSpecial(-4163) 
##################################################
# add second view - Performance_by_Region
##################################################

$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(2)
$Worksheet.Name = "Performance_by_Region" 

$csvFileNameWithPath = "$($InputPath)\test2.csv"
$Tempcsv = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFileNameWithPath)
$Tempsheet = $Tempcsv.Worksheets.Item(1)

$Tempsheet.UsedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
$Worksheet.Paste()
$Tempcsv.Close()
$Range = $Worksheet.UsedRange
$Range.EntireColumn.Autofit() | Out-Null

##################################################
# add third view - Performance_by_Category
##################################################

$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(3)
$Worksheet.Name = "Performance_by_Category" 

$csvFileNameWithPath = "$($InputPath)\test3.csv"
$Tempcsv = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFileNameWithPath)
$Tempsheet = $Tempcsv.Worksheets.Item(1)

$Tempsheet.UsedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
$Worksheet.Paste()
$Tempcsv.Close()
$Range = $Worksheet.UsedRange
$Range.EntireColumn.Autofit() | Out-Null

##################################################
# last step - select the sheet that should be shown when 
# file is opened in excel
##################################################
$ObjWorksheet = $WorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
[void] $ObjWorksheet.Activate()

##################################################
# save
##################################################
$outputFileNameWithPath = "$($OutputPath)\$($OutputFile)"
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputFileNameWithPath, 51) # saved as xlsx file
$Excel.Quit()
```

Here are screenshots of the final workbook that I want:

Screenshot 1:

[image: Example of final Workbook image 1]

Screenshot 2:

[image: Example of final Workbook image 2]

I want the red color if a value is great than 0 in these columns

16 to 20    21 to 25    26 to 30    Over 30

Comment: This is not a *task*. It's a series of tasks. So break it into it's parts, and work on the first part (adding the multiple files to one sheet). When you have that working, then start working on adding the third file to it's own sheet. When you have that working, start working on adding the formatting. If you run into difficulties along the way, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the **relevant** portions of your code, and ask a **specific question** about that code. Expecting us to do it all when you've just dumped a bunch of code and a couple of images is unreasonable.

Comment: seriously if you dont do do this everyday, do it manually

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I was able to break it all apart and work on each task at a time and got everything to work except the color coding based off condition. However I do has a specific question on how i color coded the last line from the CSV file. I always want to color code the last line from the CSV file. The number of rows in the CSV file will change. I was able to get it work, but my question: is there a more efficient way of coding it. The code is below in an Answer. I could not figure out how to add it to this question

Comment: And yes. I need to run this 3 times a day everyday. So im trying to get it automated

Answer (score 0):

```
$LastRow = $serverInfoSheet.UsedRange.rows.count
Write-Output $LastRow
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
```